# Optional endpoint authentication for certain routes in Express.js

Tags: node.js, authentication, express

What are some methods for requiring authentication for *some* API Endpoints but not for others?

Ideally, "writable" endpoints such as `DELETE /users/{user_id}` or `PUT /items/{item_id}` would require authentication, while readonly endpoints like `GET /items` would not.

One possible solution is would be a manual function call within each request handler, but that isn't very DRY:

```
app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
    res.status(200).send();
});

app.post('/users', function(req, res) {
    if (!req.authenticated) return res.status(401).send();
    work();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it in the middleware **app.use** with the **req.method**.This will have the http verb(GET,PUT,DELETE,POST)

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.method === 'POST' || req.method === 'PUT' || req.method === 'DELETE') {
        if (!req.authenticated) return res.status(401).send();
        next();
    }
});
```

If you are using epxress 4.0+ then we could use the router.use middleware.

```
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.method === 'POST' || req.method === 'PUT' || req.method === 'DELETE') {
        if (!req.authenticated) return res.status(401).send();
        next();
    }
});
```

for the routes you would be using router.get/post/put/delete rather than app.get/post/put/delete.